# mvvmcross xamarin.forms PictureChooser

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to develop a photo app using the PictureChooser plugin. I see that the sample uses Xamarin.iOS. I've googled for examples where the plugin uses Xamarin.Forms but can't find any. I understand how binding works for labels, text editors, and buttons; however, the binding btw the page's image control and the viewmodel's byte[] has got me stomped.

DAA.UI project:

In CameraPage.XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage"
               Source="{Binding Bytes, Converter={StaticResource InMemoryImage}}"
               Aspect="Fill"
               HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=300, Android=250}"
               WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=300, Android=250}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

In App.XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="DamageAssessmentApp.UI.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:DAA.UI.Resources"
    xmlns:local="using:DAA.UI"
    xmlns:nativeValueConverters="using:DAA.UI.NativeValueConverters">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!--  Application resource dictionary  -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <resources:Colors />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <nativeValueConverters:NativeInMemoryImageValueConverter x:Key="InMemoryImage"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Value Converter file:

```
using MvvmCross.Forms.Converters;
namespace DAA.UI.NativeValueConverters
{
    public class NativeInMemoryImageValueConverter : MvxNativeValueConverter<MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter>
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler can't find MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter in the value converter file.

Comment: A nice alternative is Xamarin Community Toolkit [Camera View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview). There are some examples available. Or maybe [Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) From Xamarin.Essentials

Comment: Thanks will look into the Xamarin Community Toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVMCross you should find an example that works with Xamarin.Forms, in which case a good place to start it's their [Github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross).

Or you have to implement it in each platform and use a DependencyService to get the implementation

**Other Alternatives**

1. Xamarin Community Toolkit

Another alternative for a camera App is Xamarin Community Toolkit [Camera View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview). In that same link there is an example.  But there are more examples in their [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/samples). This is fully compatible with Xamarin.Forms and brings a little more control over the CameraView

2. Xamarin.Essentials

Xamarin.Essentials offers the [MediaPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) that  let's the user upload a photo from the gallery or take a new one. But the action of the photo in handled by the OS, so for you it's like a black box. You call the function, and get the photo.

Comment: Media Picker works similar to PictureChooser and works as advertised.